# How to set HTML elements into session grails

Tags: java, session, grails, groovy

In my grails application I need to set html tags to the session. For example

```
session.setAttribute("message","<font color=\"green\">Successfully Processed</font>")
```

but when I am fetching the value from the GSP (like `${session.message}`) the opening and closing tags get changed to `&lt;`
So the whole text gets printed as such. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to encoding. The [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/security.html#codecs) explains the details and why. In your case you want to use `raw` like this:

`${raw(session.message)}`

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks a lot.